# Get html camera width and height

Tags: html, video, capture, screen-size

I'm seeing some code about capture video in html5

It  works fine with this tutorial,(http://www.html5rocks.com/ko/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

but it differently work each device. phone and my notebook. 
Because phone and my notebook's cam screen size are different.

So, I want to get each device's camera width and height, and adjust code with this value.

How can I get these values? or How can I get each device's whole screen value ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use loadedmetadata event to get video height and width.

```
video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function () {
            find_video_size();
        }, false);

function find_video_size(){
        if (isStreaming++ <= 10) {
            // videoWidth isn't always set correctly in all browsers
            if (video.videoWidth > 0){
                cwidth = video.videoWidth;
                cheight = video.videoHeight;// / (video.videoWidth / cwidth);
                $("#tutcanvas").attr("width", cwidth).attr("height", cheight);
                isStreaming = 11;
            }else{
                setTimeout(find_video_size, 200);
            }
        }else{
            $("#tutcanvas").attr("width", cwidth).attr("height", cheight);
        }
    }
```